# Cultivated a new tag, Cultivation

Tags: discussion

Added [cultivation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultivation) after running into yet another [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) query regarding it. Went ahead and tagged a number of older questions on the topic, although I halted around 5 or so so as to avoid spamming the site. I'll admit that it's not really my genre of fiction, but it seems to come up often enough, generally as part of a [manga](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) query, although it's more often an *manhua* from China.

Comment: I did wonder why there were suddenly so many of these questions crowding the front page. A fair tag, I think

Comment: I can see people adding this tag to any sort of question related to agriculture ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Possibly. I know we had a lot of people using the [tag:portal] tag for the game and for "portal fantasies". :)

Comment: Time to add this tag to all the [tag:cosmere] questions about [tag:Cultivation].

Comment: Why [tag:cultivation] instead of [tag:xianxia]?

Comment: @SQB: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/non-english-tags-redux

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yes, and following those guidelines I think [tag:xianxia] would've been a good tag name as well. I'm not saying it's _wrong_ to chosen [tag:cultivation], though.

Comment: Perhaps [tag:xianxia] as a synonym?

Comment: That would be reasonable. As I understand it, it would have to become a tag first.

Comment: And [suggested](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/cultivation/synonyms)

Comment: Maybe it should be tagged as [tag:xianxia] rather than [tag:cultivation], since that's the actual name of the genre? It looks like the former tag already existed, too, so maybe they should be merged?

Comment: I'm open to discussion. We have [a Meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/non-english-tags-redux) that recommends against non-English tags, and "cultivation" seems like the more common term used in questions. The "xianxia" tag was added by me in an attempt to merge the two as synonyms.